# Comparing tasks in freertos

Tags: embedded, real-time, microcontroller, freertos

I have an (cpp)object which can be shared across multiple tasks but is owned by a single task(owner task handle is saved when the object is created in TaskHandle_t ownerTask). Now, when I run a certain function of that object, I need to check if the current task which has requested that function execution is the owner task.

How can I test if the current task is the same whose handle is already saved? The catches are that configuse_TRACE_FACILITY is set to 0 in the project(and is meant to be like that) and hence the TCB(which is what the handles point to) doesn't have the member uxTaskNumber.

Is it a good idea to add a member in the TCB by yourself that keeps track of the task number like for example taskID and then set it while the task is being added to the ready list?

Answer (score 2):

There's a `xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle()` function that returns `TaskHandle_t` which is what I assume what you want.

**However**, the real question is why would you want such functionality in the first place. To me this sounds like you're trying to create some kind of your own resource ownership logic - why not use mutexes? If your goal is to not use given object by tasks other than the one originally creating it, you could for example embed a recursive mutex (rather than task handle) inside the object, then take the mutex without ever giving it back. Then the logic that checks for object ownership could simply attempt to take the mutex with 0 wait time.

Comment: Very good answer! I agree that comparing task handles will do what OP asks for without any configurable add-on features, and I agree that the question is whether it is bad design to ask for the task ID from within the task in general.

Comment: ok, the application sits on freeRTOS and before the system enters freeRTOS tasks, configuration is done via some objects. Now the requirement is to allow modification to these objects as per their desired owner tasks

Comment: Then what you're saying is that you want to use some of the RTOS functionality (retrieving task handles in this example) before RTOS actually runs. This isn't what I'd call a clean design. If they ever decide to change the implementation in a way that changes this behavior - for example assign task handle values after RTOS is started - then your code will break. Personally I'd create a task that does the configuration, then use mutexes to handle ownership. If you still want to go your way, then there's the `xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle()` function that I've mentioned above.